# The class X was not found in the chain configured namespaces Y

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I got multiple bundles with different dbal connections and experience a problem within the mapping configuration.
Here's the error :
`The class 'Mine\DocumentationBundle\Entity\Category' was not found in the chain configured namespaces Mine\xDb\Entity`

**config.yml:**

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: x
        connections:
            x:
                driver host port...
            cms:
                driver host port...
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                connection: x
                mappings:
                    MineXDbBundle
            cms:
                connection: cms
                mappings:
                    MineDocumentationBundle: ~
```

The output of `bin/console config:dump-reference` :

```
---------------------------- ------------------------ 
  Bundle name                  Extension alias         
 ---------------------------- ------------------------ 
  ...
  MineDocumentationBundle                               
  MineXDbBundle                mine_x_db         
  OrbitaleCmsBundle            orbitale_cms 
  ...
```

The output of `bin/console doctrine:mapping:info --em=default` :

```
Found 75 mapped entities:
[OK]   (all OK for Mine\xDB\Entity\*)...
```

The output of `bin/console doctrine:mapping:info --em=cms` :

```
Found 4 mapped entities:
[OK]   Mine\DocumentationBundle\Entity\Page
[OK]   Mine\DocumentationBundle\Entity\Category
[OK]   Orbitale\Bundle\CmsBundle\Entity\Category
[OK]   Orbitale\Bundle\CmsBundle\Entity\Page
```

Both `Orbitale\Bundle\CmsBundle\OrbitaleCmsBundle()` and `Mine\DocumentationBundle\MineDocumentationBundle(),` are registrer into AppKernel, and I successfully create tables with the command 
`bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force -em=cms`

I know I miss something but i didn't manage to solve this.

Comment: Have you tried to dump the autoloader again? `composer dump-autoloader`?

Comment: dump-autoload nor clearing cache doesn't change a thing. I think the problem is in the config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the real problem. The error was thrown in Orbitale Bundle controller at this line :

```
$categories = $this->get('orbitale_cms.category_repository');
```

Meaning the currrent entity manager doesn't have any `CategoryEntity` defined.
So i added a file to change the entity manager loaded by this bundle.

**Mine/DocumentationBundle/Ressources/config/services.yml**

```
services:
    orbitale_cms.page_repository:
        class: Orbitale\Bundle\CmsBundle\Repository\PageRepository
        factory: ['@doctrine.orm.cms_entity_manager', 'getRepository']
        arguments:
            - "%orbitale_cms.page_class%"
        calls:
            - [ 'setConfig', ['%orbitale_cms.cache%'] ]

    orbitale_cms.category_repository:
        class: Orbitale\Bundle\CmsBundle\Repository\CategoryRepository
        factory: ['@doctrine.orm.cms_entity_manager', 'getRepository']
        arguments:
            - "%orbitale_cms.category_class%"
        calls:
            - [ 'setConfig', ['%orbitale_cms.cache%'] ]
```

That's it.